# .htaccess freindly url help on Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

If I want to use .htaccess to rewriting this:

```
http://example.com/article.php?article_id=79
```

to this:

```
http://example.com/article/my-cool-and-special-article-79.html
```

what is the rewriting I need to do?

Comment: I am not sure which part you want to put in the browser.. User puts the "my-cool-and-specia~" link to browser?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is going to be that Apache will not be able to determine what friendly URL to use from an ID. I think what you want to do is to do the rewrite the other way. What CMS are you using?

Comment: I'm not using CMS,it's just an exercise,and I got a bit lost,so I want to see the answer and understand it from there

Comment: Gotcha. Typically how this would work is that the URL you would "hit" would be the my-cool-and-special-article-79.html "page" and the Apache rewrite would parse out the ID and then do the rewrite and render the same page as if you were to hit article.php?id=79. The rewrite would look something like this:

Comment: hi,I dont see what you write after "something like this:"?

Answer (score 0):

Not a machine where I can test, so you may need to dink with it. But, it would look something like this:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^article [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\-article\-([0-9]+)\.php$ /article.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: where is the part the "my-cool-and-special-article-79.html" should be written? tnx